# Can't activate python venv environment from Makefile

Tags: python, makefile, python-venv

I'm trying to activate my virtual environment with a Makefile command but I'm getting an error when I run below.

**Command**

```
make env
```

**Error**

```
Makefile:20: warning: overriding commands for target `make'
Makefile:17: warning: ignoring old commands for target `make'
source ../env/bin/activate
make: source: No such file or directory
make: *** [env] Error 1
```

**Makefile**

```
...
env:
    source ../env/bin/activate
```

- The environment exists one directory above the directory with the Makefile.
- Other Makefile commands work.
- `source ../env/bin/activate` on the command line works.

I wonder if there is something special about Makefiles I don't understand that is causing this to fail?

Comment: The target is just `env`, not `make env`.

Comment: Add your answer to the answer section instead of a part of the question!

Comment: While this is marked as "solved", sourcing like that in a makefile actually does nothing.

Comment: @jordanm I've removed that now. Actually not solved. Is there another way to make it work?

Comment: As you discovered, make targets and prerequisites cannot contain whitespace.  There are still many problems with your makefile.  As jordanm mentions the first problem is that this does absolutely nothing: make starts a shell, the shell runs the `source activate` command which updates _that shell's_ environment, then the shell exits and all changes are lost.  It's not possible to use make (or any other program) to modify your current shell's configuration.  Finally, make runs the POSIX sh `/bin/sh` and `source` is not a valid command: you need to use `.` instead.

Comment: Since you haven't clearly defined what "it" is in _make it work_ it's hard to say.  There are two things it could mean: either the environment is in effect for your current shell after `make` exits, or the environment is in effect for other commands in your makefile but not after `make` exits.  The first is impossible.  The second is hard but can be done, at least  somewhat.

Comment: @tim_xyz no, make is in a separate process so it can't alter your current running shell. Looks like you are trying to replicate [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more layers to this and you will probably find yourself with your next step, but one at a time. Recipes are executed in shell, more specifically, by default I reckon in our case as well, `/bin/sh` which does not understand `source`, so... change your `Makefile` to say:

```
env:
        . ../env/bin/activate
```

Or define make `SHELL` variable to say `/bin/bash` and it will appear to work:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
env:
        source ../env/bin/activate
```

But, next thing... line of a recipe does `fork()` its own shell (environment), so changes you've made to one shell instance (by sourcing a script), does not affect the next one. You could get around that and spawn just one shell by concatenating multiple recipes commands to actually being one line (escaping newlines and separating commands with `;` instead:

```
env:
        . ../env/bin/activate ; \
        SOME_COMMAND
```

But this is still only effective for the commands that are part of that one command line.

You might consider doing the same in multiple recipes, but really, if you need the environment to be active for whatever happens in the make, you may just wan to activate it first before calling make.